# MSP430 external port interrupt

Tags: external, interrupt, bitmask, msp430, lcd

I am trying get an external interrupt and blink an LED, but I get an error like:

```
pragma vector = accepts numeric arguments or "unused_interrupts" but not PORT_VECTOR
```

The code is as follows:

```
int main(){
    // Stop Watch Dog Timer
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;
    P1DIR &= ~BIT4; //configure as an input
    P1OUT |= BIT4;  
    P3DIR |= BIT4; 
    P3OUT |= BIT4;          
    P1IES = 0x01; 
    P1IE = 0x01; //1b = Corresponding port interrupt enabled
    P1IFG = 0x01; //PxIFG flag is set with a high-to-low transition
    P1REN = 0x01; //Pullup or pulldown enabled
}

#pragma vector = PORT_VECTOR
__interrupt void Port_1 (void){

if( (P1IN & BIT4)==0 ){ 
    // read input as GND  
    P3OUT |= BIT4;
}
else if( (P1IN & BIT4)==1   ){
    P3OUT &= ~BIT4;
}
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that code from?

Comment: Where did you get the name `PORT_VECTOR` from?

Comment: i do the programming on code composer studio 6. this code was done for MSP430fFR5739

Comment: it should be #pragma vector = PORT1_VECTOR